# Server timeout if 2 devices are used in the same network

Tags: debian, networking, firewall, timeout

I have 2 devices: a computer and a Android smartphone on the same network, if a do like 10 requests on my server with my Android phone, I have a timeout when I try to do the request with my computer during around 30 seconds. But if I do the same test with 2 different networks I don't have the timeout problem.

I check my logs, Firewalld and Fail2Ban and I can't find where is coming from. My server provide have an Anti-DDoS protection but I don't think that is the problem with 15 requests in 5 seconds.

My server is not on the same network, it is hosted by OVH (France)

- Debian 9
- Apache 2
- PHP FPM 8.0

When I have timeout with requests from my computer, I can do requests with the Smartphone.

If you have any idea where I can check, thank you.

**Edit**:
Here is my fail2ban configuration:

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-multiport
banaction_allports = iptables-allports
ignoreip = xx.xx.xx.xx
#backend = polling
bantime = 3000

[sshd]

enabled = true
port    = ssh
maxretry = 2

[ssh-ddos]

enabled = true
port    = ssh,sftp
filter  = sshd-ddos
maxretry = 2

[webmin-auth]

enabled = true
port    = 10000

[proftpd]

enabled  = true
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data

[postfix]

enabled  = true
port     = smtp,465,submission
maxretry = 2

[dovecot]

enabled = true
port    = pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps,submission,465,sieve

[postfix-sasl]

enabled  = true
port     = smtp,465,submission,imap,imaps,pop3,pop3s
maxretry = 2

[block-all-dem-noobs]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = block-all-dem-noobs
logpath = /var/log/virtualmin/xxx.com_access_log
maxretry = 50
findtime = 30
bantime = 600
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

The `block-all-dem-noobs` is on another domain name.

**Edit 2**:
I continue my tests and here some notes:

- when I have timeouts, if I connect to a VPN with the computer I can access to the page
- when I have timeouts, I can connect to my server with SSH
- on the smartphone, it is an application (React Native) that send requests to an API on my server (Apache/PHP)
- on the smartphone, if I try to send a lot of requests with Chrome, I don't have timeouts on my computer.

So it is only when I use the mobile application and timeouts are only with Apache (80/443)

**Edit 3**:
Even if in stop fail2ban I still have the problem.

Comment: I would point to the router for such issues

Comment: what server...?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella So you think that the problem is coming from my server provider ? (OVH)

Comment: @user253751 A LAMP server: Debian 9 Apache 2 PHP FPM 8.0

Comment: Didn't get that that was a datacenter server issue (was thinking about a at-home server). You may want to check with them, you might be tripping for some obscure reasons that anti-DDOS @Julien

Comment: @roaima it is edited, thank you.

Comment: What if you make 10 requests from the computer and then another request from the computer?

Comment: @user253751 I forgot to mention, I don't have timeout with the device that I did 10 requests

Comment: Julien, please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/701109/edit) to provide information, such as the 10 requests. Don't put this in the comments - I've already explained that it's too easy for such information to be missed.

Comment: `fail2ban` is good at picking up fast sequences of invalid web requests. Are you getting a real page during your tests (even if it's a simple test page)? 15 requests in 5 seconds should not trigger the OVH DDOS - I suspect it's your `fail2ban` configuration

Comment: @roaima it was what I was thinking too, but I checked logs and my jail.local without find anything. I have edited the post with the configuration.